# Se ha detenido la aplicación en dispositivo fisico pero en emulador funciona bien

Tags: android

Cuando ejecuto el app en el emulador todo funciona bien, pero cuando ejecuto el app en un dispositivo físico se detiene la aplicación, en el emulador tengo un nexus 6 con android 5.0 API 21, el dispositivo físico es un alcatel one touch pixi con kitkat 4.4 y este es mi archivo `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "matgic.com.matgic"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Por lo poco que se, Material Design es un tema de Android 5.0, ¿Es posible hacerlo compatible para versiones a partir de 4.0? y si asi fuera ¿Cómo?

Código del xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="matgic.com.matgic.User">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="25sp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="25sp">

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#3e2bea"
    android:text="Score:"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtscore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#3e2bea"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


/>

<!--
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#f76b1f"
        app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#edaa86"
        app:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#f7f6f5"
        app:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    >
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/digits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="Digits"
        android:onClick="irSaludo"
    />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/action_b"
       app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
       app:fab_size="mini"
       app:fab_title="Menu 2"
    />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/action_c"
       app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
       app:fab_size="mini"
       app:fab_title="Menu 3"
    />


    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cuidado con el uso del + cuando añadas liberias, ya que puedes tener problemas futuras actualizaciones. y material desing es para android <5

Comment: Para mayor detalle incluye tu LogCat, Puede ser un error no relacionado a lo que comentas.

Comment: @Ashley G. Gracias por la observación

Comment: @Jorgesys agregué la linea que me has dicho (compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0') en el build.gradle y aún persistia el problema,  entonces comenté por un momento
 la parte del material design en mi xml y ejecuté el app en el dispositivo fisico y funciona bien, 
si es el Material Design el que ocasiona mi problema, en la pregunta adjunté el código de mi xml

Comment: Entonces si lo comentas y funciona bien no necesitas la library de design. El LogCat es importante para no estar a ciegas.

Comment: lo que pasa es que para que poder continuar avanzando en la app necesito ese FloatingActionsMenu de lo contrario el usuario no puede continuar desplazando en ella, quise decir que el app funciona pero quitando el floatingmenu pero si lo necesito, si carga el activity pero sin el menu del Material Design

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu aplicación funcione desde dispositivos con Android 4.0, debes definir como minimo SDK la versión 14

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

> Material Design es un tema de Android 5.0, ¿Es posible hacerlo
>   compatible para versiones a partir de 4.0? y si asi fuera ¿Cómo?

Material Design fue introducido en la API 21 (Android 5.0) pero para hacerlo compatible con versiones anteriores precisamente se usan las library de soporte, en este caso:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

El error que comentas puede no ser relacionado a "Material Design", por eso la importancia del uso del LogCat.